# LabView dbc-Translator

Tags: labview

I have a little over a month to do a project through LabView. It is a program that needs to translate information from a dbc file (dbc battery file) to a specific battery system. In other words, my LabView program should be a translator of the dbc file, which we get from the customer - since I work in a company that deals with battery testing.

Could someone help me and give me some useful advice, link or tutorial, very specific to this issue of mine?

I would be very grateful.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you elaborate what a dbc file is? Usually, it is a file describing parameters and message frames for a CAN bus, and can be read into labview to easily setup CAN communication. But the way you ask, it seems your dbc files are something different, though I don't find any more detailed information. As last resort, one needs the specification of that file type to build an own parser.

Comment: A CAN DBC file (CAN database) is a text file that contains information for decoding raw CAN bus data to 'physical values'.

https://www.csselectronics.com/screen/page/can-dbc-file-database-intro/language/en

Answer (score 1):

Since we now know that we are talking about CAN database files:

I would recommend to install National Instruments NI-XNET, which is a framework for LIN, CAN and Flexray. It can import such definition files, and makes it easy to access data from the device via the Bus in LabVIEW. There fore  an X-NET CAN/LIN/Flexray interface is needed

You can import a dbc file manually, which is OK if there's always the same DBC file.
To do so, open START > National Instruments > NI-XNET Database editor. Open a database, and load your file. You should then see a tree with lots of info. For example, you should see all available CAN frames, and what signals (values) transported in it. You'll also see which bits of a frame are used for which signal, how the bits are interpreted, and how they are converted for example into a voltage.

Finally, it's not more than this to communicate with the device. Right-click on the signal list, choose the just imported database from above, and then select the signals to read.

[image]

There is much much more, but I think this is a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much, I really appreciate your help.

I knew roughly which of the program libraries I had to use and how to approach the issue!

Your answer crystallized my thought and idea even more.

Thanks a lot!